# Footer positioning issue

Tags: css, html

Here is a sample of the problem
[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BCgnE/9/)

When you make the viewing windows smaller, so that the footer is overlapping the other content and the scroll bar appears.

When scrolling down the footer is stuck in its previous position and doesn't go back down. I don't want the footer fixed (`position:fixed`) if possible.

Could this be fixed with some thing `min/max-height` property or `z-index`?

**HTML:**

```
<header>something here</header>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora temporibus illum aliquam voluptatum at blanditiis itaque tenetur laborum officia culpa maiores quasi accusantium excepturi! Quidem alias ullam praesentium quod eius.</div>
<footer>&copy; 2014 some text</footer>
```

**CSS :**

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #333;
}
div {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
footer {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #333;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is `bottom:0` !!

I hope this is what you want -> [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BCgnE/11/)

I added `height:100%` hoping that, that is what you want.

You can change it if you want

```
html,body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #333;
}
div {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
footer {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #333;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
}
```